# PHP doesn't write a file to dir with +rw permissions

Tags: php, file, fwrite

I have a simple .php file:

```
<?php
$archivo = $_POST["name"];
$alineamiento = $_POST["alineamiento"];
$fp=fopen("$archivo","w");
fwrite($fp,$alineamiento);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

This works fine, but when I need to write the file in a subfolder (sub_mat):

```
<?php
$archivo = $_POST["name"];
$alineamiento = $_POST["alineamiento"];
$fp=fopen("/var/www/SChip/sub_mat/$archivo","w");
fwrite($fp,$alineamiento);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

this doesn't work. I also try it without the absolute path dir, like:

```
<?php
$archivo = $_POST["name"];
$alineamiento = $_POST["alineamiento"];
$fp=fopen("sub_mat/$archivo","w");
fwrite($fp,$alineamiento);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I have `rw` permissions in the sub_mat folder. I try this with Chrome, FF, and Opera, and it doesn't work. I know this must be silly but I can't figure out the problem.

EDIT

I modified the script, adding `system("mv ...")` and initializing the values.
If I run this in the Console it works fine, no errors, only:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/SChip/create-matrix.php on line 2
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alineamiento in /var/www/SChip/create-matrix.php on line 3

but that's obvious... But when I run in Chrome or FF it doesn't work, no errors or warnings. It just leaves the file in the current folder, and the `mv` is not executed.

```
<?php
$archivo = $_POST["name"];
$alineamiento = $_POST["alineamiento"];
$archivo = "testing";
$alineamiento = "test2";
$fp=fopen("$archivo","w");
fwrite($fp,$alineamiento);
fclose($fp);
system("mv $archivo custom_matrices_temporal/$archivo");
?>
```

Comment: You need to provide people with the error if you want help.

Comment: fyi: not a good idea to allow php to write to user supplied filename. you could have your index file replaced with a shell script

Comment: If not getting an error (should come thru at warning level), ensure the *filename* is not also a directory.  See note on [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) page and `is_dir()`.

Comment: If the file doesn't already exist, I believe the directory needs _execute_ permissions as well to allow the creation of new files.

Comment: yes that's was the problem... thank you

Comment: Please, please check the comment by @LawrenceCherone this script is **very** dangerous. People can overwrite your files or inject malicious code into them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory needs *execute* (`x`) permissions as well to allow the creation of new files.